# Unexpected latitude error when decoding ST_AsMVTGeom geometries

Tags: postgis, mapbox-vector-tile

I am trying to decode latitude from the MVT tiles with the minimal latitudal error. Somehow, the closer latitude to the poles, the bigger the error.

Using PostGIS, this query generates a list of tile center points for a few tiles along the Y axis. Each point is encoded using `ST_AsMVTGeom`. Afterwards, I use what I assume is the correct MVT decoding process: translate point back to global coordinates from the (x,y) tile envelope, scale to zoom 0, and convert from 3858 back to 4326.

Note that the encoding and decoding processes are assumed to be linear within 3857 cartesian coordinate system.

The result is surprising: while the X (longitude) coordinate is decoded perfectly, the Y (latitude) has a bell-curve-shaped error, going from 211 meters near poles to 2.5km!

How is it possible for the Cartesian linear coordinate system (3857) to be encoded to MVT and back with a varying error rate??  Note that simply going 4326->3857->4326 on a point does not introduce any errors.

```sql
SELECT x,
       y,
       lon,
       lat,
       st_x(d)                                                                  decoded_lon,
       st_y(d)                                                                  decoded_lat,
       lon - st_x(d)                                                            diff_x,
       lat - st_y(d)                                                            diff_y,
       st_distancespheroid(p, d)                                                distance,
       st_distancespheroid(p, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(st_x(d), st_y(p)), 4326)) distance_x,
       st_distancespheroid(p, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(st_x(p), st_y(d)), 4326)) distance_y
FROM (SELECT *,
             -- Convert MVT-encoded geometry back to 3857
             ST_Transform(st_scale(
                                  ST_Translate(v, ext * (x - 2 ^ (z - 1)), -ext * (y - 2 ^ (z - 1))),
                                  (st_xmax(st_tileenvelope(z, x, y)) - st_xmin(st_tileenvelope(z, x, y))) / ext,
                                  (st_ymax(st_tileenvelope(z, x, y)) - st_ymin(st_tileenvelope(z, x, y))) / ext
                              ), 4326) d
      FROM (SELECT *,
                   -- Convert points from lat,lng (4326) to MVT
                   ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(p, 3857), ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y), ext) v
            FROM (SELECT *, st_x(p) lon, st_y(p) lat
                  FROM (SELECT *, ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y), 4326)) p
                        FROM (SELECT 14 as z, abs(x - 1) as x, abs(y - 1) as y, 409600 as ext
                              FROM generate_series(0, (2 ^ 14)::int, (2 ^ 10)::int) as x,
                                   generate_series(0, (2 ^ 14)::int, (2 ^ 10)::int) as y) t) t) t) t) t
order by x, y;
```

Plotting distance_y grouped by the y value shows this error graph:

[image]

Comment: 3857 is **not** "Cartesian linear". The poles are infinitely far from the Equator, so it's more "Cartesian exponential".

Comment: @Vince, I meant that once in 3857, all transformations between MVT and standard 3857 should not introduce any non-linear errors.  Turns out it wasn't - it was me converting it back to 4327 and using spherical distance computation that caused non-linear error. An amazing GIS enthusiast has pointed that my computation is incorrect - the SIGN of Y value in both st_scale and st_translate should be reversed.  I will wait for him to post an answer, or will do it myself tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

As expecetd - a case of [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK).  The decoding of the MVT geometry was incorrectly reversing the Y scaling and translating coefficient.  The proper decoding in SQL should be this:

```
ST_Transform(
  st_scale(
    ST_Translate(v, ext * (x - 2 ^ (z - 1)), ext * (y - 2 ^ (z - 1))),
    (st_xmax(st_tileenvelope(z, x, y)) - st_xmin(st_tileenvelope(z, x, y))) / ext,
    -(st_ymax(st_tileenvelope(z, x, y)) - st_ymin(st_tileenvelope(z, x, y))) / ext
  ),
  4326
)
```

Huge thanks goes to Mike of [Planetiler](https://github.com/onthegomap/planetiler) fame for finding the solution.

The non-linear error was simply due to translating the values back to 4326 projection - which exacerbated the error non-linearly.